# How to Match Password Hashing Results with Apache Shiro Credential Matcher

Tags: java, mysql, hash, shiro

I am using Apache Shiro to create a web app user authentication capability. I have user login and home page JSPs adapted from the published Shiro tutorial examples. These are executed in Apache Tomcat. Shiro is configured with a JDBC Realm and the default authentication queries on user, role and permission tables in a prototype MySQL database that match the Shiro examples. Passwords are initially in clear text, and the database users table includes a salt column which is yet to be implemented. In this state, login and authentication using these components work fine and as expected.

I am now trying to implement hashed and salted passwords. My intention is that each user password has its own salt stored with it in the database. I am using a SHA-256 hash and storing the result in Base64 format. Here is the shiro.ini segment that attempts to define this configuration and in particular the credential matcher to perform the desired password hashing with salt from columns in the database:

```
# Configure the MySQL data source
ds = org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
ds.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
ds.username = ****
ds.password = ****
ds.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shiro_users

# Use salted and hashed SHA-256 passwords stored in Base64 format
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
credentialsMatcher.hashSalted = true
 
# Configure the JdbcRealm   
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.saltStyle = SaltStyle.COLUMN
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password, salt from users WHERE username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role_name FROM user_roles WHERE user_name = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT permission FROM roles_permissions WHERE role_name = ?

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
```

To populate the user database for development with hashed password and corresponding salt values, I created a prototype Java Password class. I adapted a set of methods from published examples to generate salt and hash clear text password values. Note that the hashed password and salt values are created and stored in the database in Base64 format. This is intended to be consistent with the shiro.ini setting of:

```
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
```

For the present stage of development of the Password class, the hashed password and salt values are printed to the console for manual pasting into the appropriate database columns, replacing the clear text values that have otherwise worked fine.

Here are the key methods of the java Password class:

```
public class Password {
    
    /**
     * saveHashedPassword
     * 
     * Generates salt and hashes the given clear text password. Both the hashed password
     * and salt are encoded in Base64 and saved to the user database. 
     * 
     * Note: In this development version, the password and salt Base64 strings are 
     * printed to the console for manual pasting into the appropriate database columns.
     * 
     * @param clearTextPassword The clear text password to be hashed and salted
     */
    public void saveHashedPassword (String clearTextPassword) {
        String hashedPassword;
        byte[] saltBytes;
        String salt;
        
        saltBytes = getSalt();
        hashedPassword = hashAndSaltPassword(clearTextPassword, saltBytes);
        salt = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(saltBytes);
        // persist salt and hash or return them to delegate this task to other component
        System.out.println(hashedPassword.length() + "\tpwd \t" + hashedPassword);
        System.out.println(salt.length() + "\tsalt\t" + salt);
    }
    
    /**
     * hashAndSaltPassword
     * 
     * Generates a hashed and salted Base64 password from a clear text password and
     * salt byte array.
     * 
     * @param clearTextPassword The clear text password to hash and salt
     * @param salt The byte array salt value to use in hashing
     * @return The hashed and salted password
     */
    private String hashAndSaltPassword(String clearTextPassword, byte[] salt) {
        byte[] hashedBytes;
        String hashedPassword = "";
        
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            digest.update(salt);
            hashedBytes = digest.digest(clearTextPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            hashedPassword = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashedBytes);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return hashedPassword;
    }
    
    /**
     * getSalt
     * 
     * Generates a salt byte array
     * 
     * @return A byte array salt value
     */
    private byte[] getSalt() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
}
```

For a clear text password of “secret”,  Password,hashAndSaltPassword() returns the following values (printed to the console and manually pasted into the appropriate database columns):

```
Password:   mKYfzHXt4kHoLgzc7/C2upKXuCZ0SSGjUrnGIqzd92E=
Salt:       bigG9fGM9mjcqNiprFQ4+g==
```

When the web app executes with the hashed password Shiro.ini configuration and the hashed password and salt values above in the database, the login process fails. (It worked fine before applying the password hash.) No exceptions are thrown and neither Shiro nor Tomcat gives any diagnostic other than the login fails. No errors are reported in the normal app logs.

It appears that the result of Shiro's hash of the clear text password at run time and the stored hashed password and salt in the database produced by the Password.hashAndSaltPassword() method do not match. I think there is something inconsistent between the configuration of the Shiro credential matcher and the means of creating the stored hashed and salted password, but I have been unable to diagnose the problem further or find a specific example that illuminates the use case completely.

Any help diagnosing the problem, referral to appropriate resources or other constructive observations or suggestions are much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Quick mobile half answer, take a look at https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/tools/hasher/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/tools/hasher/Hasher.java   And [the doc](https://shiro.apache.org/command-line-hasher.html) to see one way you can generate a hash in a known good format. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am aware of the command line hasher, but I need to create my own GUI/web password utilities that ultimately save a valid hashed/salted password in a database. Embedding a command line utility in other GUI classes seems awfully cumbersome. It seems like a java method to perform the hashing in a manner consistent with the Shiro process should be almost as straightforward as configuring the credentialsMatcher in Shiro.ini. Can you point to any resource or examples that would illustrate this? Am I missing something? Thanks again for responding.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your suggestion. On closer examination of the command line hasher source, I can see how to craft the methods I'll need from the components it uses. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I used the shiro-tools-Hasher to hash a password. It generated hashed and salted output as expected. I pasted this value into the password field of a user record in the database. I left the separate salt field empty and the auth query only references the password field. I set the JdbcRealm SaltStyle to "CRYPT" in Shiro.ini, and it appears to initialize without error. The login JSP executes as expected but a login using the user and password values in the database fails, without error message or exception. Am I treating the hashed password value properly for authentication to work? Suggestions?

Comment: Without error or exception? You might just need to turn the logging up.  Invalid passwords are a _normaly_ occurring event and logging them at a warn/error level would likely cause log sam